# Windows 10 Start Menu Won't Open, Other Apps OK

Tags: windows-10

After an unscheduled reboot last night one of our designer's machines running Windows 10 is not working as expected - specifically, **the start menu won't open**.

Unlike many similar issues, File Explorer, Metro Apps, Windows Store etc work fine. It's opening the start menu and right-clicking on taskbar items that doesn't work.

Looking through the event logs the following was logged just before last shutdown:

```
Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards. No user action is required.  

DETAIL - 
  21 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-4067970951-1747624916-1673675669-1001...:
```

This is followed by a long list of registry key handles.

Then, first thing the next day:

```
Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App failed with error: Invalid value for registry See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

Looking in `Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI-Operational log` we find:

```
Activation of the app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: Invalid value for registry.
```

Thus far we've tried:

- Reboot (no change)
- Create new admin user account (no change, issue affects both accounts)
- Running `SFC /scannow` (nothing found)
- Performing a Windows 10 'Reset' (can't, as it's booting off a USB hard drive, which Windows considers 'Windows to Go').
- Running Powershell cmdlets (no change):

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

- Using a Linux USB key to boot into another OS and copy `System32/config/RegBack` to `System32/config` (no difference, even though the RegBack files were from 3 days prior)
- Running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` (no change)

And I'm running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could [try the troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12385/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-opening-start-menu-cortana). If you are not on the Creators Update, you may consider updating.

Comment: Alas I have also tried that to no avail. Will update question with full details when I have full access to machine later today.

Comment: Then all I can offer is [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). If that does not work, then I cannot think of anything else than a full re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

These are my ideas in addition to your almost exhaustive list :

1. [Try the troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12385/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-opening-start-menu-cortana).
2. If you are not on the Creators Update, you may consider updating.
3. [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
4. If nothing works, then I cannot think of anything else than a full re-installation.